# module not found pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, deployment, wsgi, pythonanywhere

I have deployed my site on pythonanywhere.
the link to the site is
`AbuTheRayhan.pythonanywhere.com`
but the server says

```
Something went wrong :-(
Something went wrong while trying to load this website; please try again later.

If it is your site, you should check your logs to determine what the problem is.
```

On error log

```
Error running WSGI application
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'streamer'
 File "/var/www/abutherayhan_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
 application = get_wsgi_application()
```

wsgi.py code is

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/AbuTheRayhan/video_uploader_with_django/streamer/video_streamer/video_streamer'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'streamer.settings'


from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

the problem is here(os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'streamer.settings'
).
What they exactly want me to write here?

Comment: go to ```Files``` and set ```DEBUG = True``` and let me know what error is showing.

Comment: @TariqAhmed it remains the same. Is there any problem with directory?  video uploader with django has stremer folder. streamer has the venv(V Environment) and video_streamer project. video_streamer has other video_streamer app where the settings.py is.

Comment: ```settings.py``` file is in your ```project directory``` which was created by ```django-admin```

Comment: @TariqAhmed can you tell me what exactly i have to write ```'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'streamer.settings' ```  in the place of streamer.settings? I mean What python anywhere wants me to write here?

Comment: Write your project name on the place of ```streamer``` like ```your_project_name.settings```

Comment: The problem is not your DJANGO_SETTINGS value, it's the directory that you're using for your project directory. See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject/#edit-your-wsgi-file

Comment: @Glenn I have deployed three project but all says the same. i tried almost every way possible.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `/home/AbuTheRayhan/video_uploader_with_django/streamer/video_streamer/video_streamer/streamer/settings.py` exists or change either the `path` or `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` value to match your actual project file structure.